# Efficient serialization: spit, with-out-str, pr

Tags: clojure

I have a piece of code which looks as follows:

```
(defn dump [path blob]
  (spit path
    (with-out-str (pr blob))))
```

This is dumping out GBs of data. Is there am more efficient way of doing this? (without creating the intermediate string that with-out-str creates)?

Comment: What is `blob`?

Comment: Normally I would use `pr-str`, but this won't help speed since it uses `with-out-str` internally.

Comment: @AlanThompson : "blob" is meant to be anything that I can write out with pr and read back in with clojure.edn/read-string -- we don't know any additional information about "blob"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built in serilization functions use the dynamically bound variable `*out*` to define where they write to:

```
user> (def data [1 2 3 4 5])
#'user/data

user> (with-open [output (clojure.java.io/writer "/tmp/data.edn")]
        (binding [*out* output]
          (prn data)))
nil
user> (slurp "/tmp/data.edn")
"[1 2 3 4 5]\n"
```

So if you bind this to a file writer (remember to close it, and beware of lazy-evaluation and closing file descriptors) then all the output will go strait to that file. `pr` and `prn` will write in a format that makes sure it can be read back. The other print functions will write it a way that's easier for humans and not guaranteed for computers.